# Back/Forward navigation in Word 2003/2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003

I've been using Adobe Acrobat Reader since version 4. While I am reading a PDF document, I can use the Back/Forward buttons to navigate between the previously browsed pages.

For example, I am on page 6 in Acrobat Reader, and I click a cross-referenced link to page 70; I can go **BACK** to page 6 by hitting the back button.

Is there any such functionality available in Microsoft Word 2003/2007? There has to be something like it, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: Don't use the term M$ to refer to Microsoft - Just makes you sound like an idiot. If you don't like them, use something else.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Wil! It was really annoying to see that.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the edit :) I used it coz, in fact, I quite like them.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, BUT, these things work only when we are navigating in the document by clicking cross-links/index links. But, that's not what I want. I want to do something like Acrobat Reader. I'll still keep the question open for the next couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the toolbar, and add the **Web** toolbar. Then, just use the forward and Back buttons.

Comment: Ummm, where can I find the Web toolbar in Office 2007 :{ ?

Comment: I also tried it in Office 2003, but the Back/Forward buttons are disabled!

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a toolbar in Word 2007 or an equivalent toolbar. My solution works with Word 2003 and almost all previous versions. I haven't really used Word 2007 that much.

Comment: That's strange. It works for me. I use it at work a lot when reading design documents.

Comment: Alex, I tried opening a BIG document in Word 2003, made some changes to page 3, then pressed CTRL+End to move to the end of the document; but, the Back/Forward buttons remain disabled!

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. Sorry it doesn't help!

Comment: How come you chose my answer as the accepted one?

Comment: Try it: it doesn't work. Open a big document and press control+end. It doesn't take you back! The button remains disabled. It only works if you navigate by clicking internal document links.

Answer (score 4):

In Word 2007, you can use ALT + the left and right arrows.

Comment: This also works in Word 2003 (for cross-references etc).

Comment: It doesn't work. And look in the official shortcuts list: it isn't listed http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HA102748895.aspx#top

Answer (score 1):

**With Microsoft Word 2007:**

Click the Office Orb -> Word Options

Then go to Customize, and under `Choose commands from:`, select `All Commands`.  Then, just add the `Back` and `Forward` buttons, and they will appear at the top, near the Save & Undo buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyboard shortcut that takes you back up to 4 places, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. No more <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> induced rage!!

Source: Official Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Word http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HA102748895.aspx#top

Answer (score -1):

- In Word 2010, right-click on a blank area in the toolbar and select
  'Customize Quick Access Toolbar...' or 'Customize the Ribbon...'
  (preferably the latter).
- The Word Options window should appear.
- In the Choose commands from: drop-down select 'All Commands'.
- Scroll down to find the green Back button.
- Click Add.
- You may need to create a New Group using pane on the right of the
  Word Options window.
- Follow the instructions.
- Repeat with the Forward button.