# Where are the Back and Forward browse buttons in MS-Word - 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back/Forward navigation in Word 2003/2007](https://superuser.com/questions/37656/back-forward-navigation-in-word-2003-2007)

Hi,

I am using MS-Word in Office-2007. I remember in older version of word(2003), there was a button like a web browser back arrow and forward arrow So when one clicks on some link in the document to another page, to come back to the original page, one could click the back arrow button.

How do I enable this tool button in MS-Word 2007?

Thank you.

-AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not currently have Word 2007, but I have used it. I believe that if you just right click on the tool bar and add the Web tool bar. This should give you the desired buttons.

Another way to do it is to Click the Office Orb, then click word options. Now go to Customize, and under Choose commands from:, select All Commands. Then, just add the Back and Forward buttons, and they will appear at the top, near the Save & Undo buttons.

If this doesn't work, a workaround could be to press Alt+left or right arrow keys. I would test these items that I found on the internet, but like I said earlier, I do not have access to Word 2007. All helpful information in this document was found at the following link: [Back/Forward navigation in Word 2003/2007](https://superuser.com/questions/37656/back-forward-navigation-in-word-2003-2007).

Good Luck-

Answer (score 3):

If you mean Like This below:
[image]

Simply click on the drop down arrow to the left and select **More Commands**
Then in the Chhose commands from Dropdown Box select **All commands**
Add in the Back and Forwards Command

you can alternatively do:
Alt + Left to go Back
Alt + Right to go forwards